# Алгоритмы. Сколько раз вызывается print() в функции? Временная сложность циклов с половинным делением i /= 2

Tags: python, алгоритм, time-complexity

Сколько раз вызывается print() в зависимости от параметра n?

```
def f5(n):
    i = n
    while i > 0:
        j = i
        while j > 0:
            print(i, j)
            j = j - 1
        i = i // 2

def f6(n):
    i = n
    while i > 0:
        j = i
        while j > 0:
            print(i, j)
            j = j // 2
        i = i - 1
```

Comment: А просто запустить нельзя? Там будет сумма логарифмов чисел во 2 случае и сумма чисел без последних бит в первом.

Comment: @pavel "просто запустить" даже для умеренно больших n долго выполняться может.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `T(n) = T(n-1) + c`, где `T(n)`—это количество шагов, выполняемых циклом при заданном `n`, то [`T(n) = O(n)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28n%29+%3D+f%28n-1%29+%2B+c). Если `T(n) = T(n/2) + c`, то [`T(n) = O(log(n))`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28n%29+%3D+f%28n%2F2%29+%2B+c).

В первом случае внутренний цикл повторяется: `n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... ~ n`, [учитывая что](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20n%2F2%5Ek,k%3D1..log2%28n%29):

[image: $sum_(k=1)^((log(n))/(log(2))) n/2^k = n-1$]

То есть `f5(n)`—это [`O(n)` алгоритм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%ABO%C2%BB_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%C2%ABo%C2%BB_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5), не смотря на то что на первый взгляд код в `f5()` может выглядеть как `O(n log n)` алгоритм.

С другой стороны, точное значение можно легко найти, используя Питон, просто заменив `print()` в коде вопроса на `count += 1` и заметив, что [вложенный цикл выполняется `i` раз](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28n%29+%3D+f%28n-1%29+%2B+1,f%280%29%3D0), что позволяет заменить его на `count += i`:

```
def count_f5(n):
    count = 0
    if n >= 0:
        i = n
        #  abcde
        # + abcd
        # +  abc
        # +   ab
        # +    a
        while i: # log(n) iterations
            count += i
            i >>= 1  # i //= 2
    return count
```

---

Во втором случае: `log(n) + log(n-1) + log(n-2) ... ~ log(n!)` [раз](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+log%28k%29,+k%3D1..n):

[image: $sum_(k=1)^n log(k) = log((1)_n)$]

То есть `f6(n)`—это [`O(log(n!)) == O(n log n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8118221/4279) алгоритм.

Чтобы получить точное количество `print()` вызовов в `f6()`, достаточно заметить, что каждый `j //= 2` во вложенном цикле отбрасывает одну  цифру в двоичном представлении `j`, поэтому общее количество итерацией во вложенном цикле равно количеству цифр в двоичном представлении `i`, то есть [`i.bit_length()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) на Питоне, метод который возвращает количество бит в числе.

Тогда точное число `print()` вызовов в `f6()` можно найти, используя прямолинейный цикл по `i`:

```
def count_f6_bruteforce(n):
    return sum(i.bit_length() for i in range(1, n+1))
```

Этот код [можно упростить и свести к явной формуле](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+i*2%5E%28i-1%29,i%3D1..k):

```
def count_f6(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 0
    # 2**(nbits - 1) <= n < 2**nbits
    nbits = n.bit_length()
    return nbits * (n + 1) - 2**nbits + 1
```

Comment: Позволил себе исправить вашу вторую формулу с учетом формулы Стирлинга. Замечу, что не очень корректно **дополнить исходный вопрос и дать ответ на него** - без согласования с автором...

Comment: @Harry: спасибо за картинки. По букве вопрос расширен, но по духу это тот же вопрос (с более полезной формулировкой для данного сайта). Если подобное (небольшое) расширение автора не устраивает, можно всегда откатиться. Техника, показанная в ответе работает для обоих формулировок.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, понятно, что это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но как это записывается в аналитическом виде - Кнут его знает :) По крайней мере в *Конкретной математике* для первой формулы даны только оценки в разделе 4.4, и пояснено, что эту сумму очень легко считать в бинарном виде, отбрасывая по одному младшему биту...

**Update** На незаданный вопрос о временной сложности, естественно, не отвечал. Но если **автора** действительно интересует ответ и на этот вопрос, то

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первое определяется с учетом того, что реальное значение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так что оценку сделать легко и сверху, и снизу. Аналогичная оценка выполняется и для второго случая с учетом формулы Стирлинга

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Формула для ряда это  улучшение над явным кодом в вопросе,  но это неполное решение, если ваше намерение было найти сколько раз вызывается `print()`. К примеру, глядя на ваш ряд, не очевидно какой ответ для `n=1000_000`.