# Как навскидку оценить сложность алгоритма по времени?

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

Некоторые программисты умеют навскидку оценить сложность своего алгоритма в О-нотации, будь то C# или SQL. Как они это делают? Поделитесь источниками или объясните на пальцах. Спасибо.

Comment: На самом деле вот так на вскидку, более чем уверен что оценить алгоритм нельзя. Например быстрая сортировка на 1 взгляд совсем не очевидна сложность. А в простейших вещах просто опыта достаточно, большинство "алгоритмов" оцениваются тупо по числу вложенных циклов. А вопрос слишком общий как по мне.

Comment: по базовой скорости роста трудоёмкости (к которой нужно привести алгоритм). Их там штук 8. Выбор в пользу меньшей.

Comment: Как оценивать по числу вложенных циклов?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Какой вопрос - такой ответ... :)

Оценивается количество действий. Зачастую это приводит к некоторым рекуррентным соотношениям, которые в той или иной степени трудно решить - хотя имеются и готовые общие решения, так что оценить многие алгоритмы не так уж сложно.
Однако надо учитывать, что при оценке сложности алгоритма нужно рассматривать используемые структуры данных - например, в алгоритме Дейкстры многое зависит от того, как реализована очередь с приоритетами, да и вообще в алгоритмах на графах многое зависит от представления графа - списками смежности или матрицей...

В качестве простейшего примера - обычное перемножение матриц `nxn` - каждый элемент новой матрицы получается путем перемножения и суммирования произведений элементов соответствующей строки и столбца. Длина строки/столбца - `n`, итого, `O(n)` операций для вычисления одного элемента результирующей матрицы. Всего их `n`<sup>2</sup> - итого, сложность алгоритма `O(n`<sup>3</sup>`)`.

Тема очень обширная, так что рекомендую обратиться к [литературе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576507/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B), в особенности рекомендую [Т. Кормен, Ч. Лейзерсон, Р. Ривест, К. Штайн - *Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ*. 3-е изд. - 2013.](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1794-2.html)

Comment: Как-то можно привести упрощенную модель для оценки в уме сложностей, а именно способ составления приблизительной суперпозиции функций сложности для любой линейной программы? Кормена читать начал.

Comment: Скажем так - я затрудняюсь ответить в общем виде. Обычно рассматриваются циклы, операции с памятью... Нет, не берусь ответить на ваш вопрос. Мне кажется, у вас это придет само - с опытом.

Comment: За Кормена смелый +1. Добавлю что сложность алгоритма стоит оценивать исходя из того что у Вас будет самый худший, просто самый ужасный набор данных для работы данного алгоритма, такой набор данных который потребует максимально возможное количество итераций.

Answer (score 5):

Также как из другими "навскидку" оценками (основанными на интуиции), суть в уже усвоенном опыте: в доступности строительных блоков, которыми вы можете оперировать бессознательно в выбранной области, благодаря целенаправленной практике.

Большинство кода имеет простую алгоритмическую структуру. И если знать оценку для распространённых блоков (алгоритмов и операций над структурами данных в вашей области), то сложность кода очевидна. В C++ сложность для стандартных алгоритмов явно указана. Знание только к какой из трёх категорий ввод относится (случайный доступ/ RandomAccessIterator, последовательный/ForwardIterator, однопроходной/InputIterator) уже достаточно во многих случаях, чтобы оценить сложность алгоритма.

Можно даже не знать как что-то конкретно реализовано. К примеру, если алгоритм на каком-то шаге требует сортировки случайных данных, то разумно предположить O(n log n) для алгоритма, основанного на сравнениях, вне зависимости от конкретной реализации. Или при поиске в таблице в базе данных, если строк много (когда о big O имеет смысл говорить), можно ожидать что добротная реализация индекс создаст (поиск из O(n) в O(log n) превращается). В случае сомнений, [можно измерить](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5175925/4279).

С другой стороны, даже  [внешне похожие простые примеры кода могут иметь отличающуюся сложность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/581596/23044).

---

Чтобы найти или проверить интуитивный ответ, можно рекуррентные выражения или частичные суммы построить, которые с помощью компьютера вычислить. Так как есть `O(c*n) == O(n)` и `O(n*n + n) == O(n*n)` и другие упрощающие преобразования, то многие алгоритмы можно свести к небольшому числу базовых случаев. Процесс требует внимательности, но достаточно прямолинеен (особенно если задействовать что-нибудь вроде wolframalpha, Maple, Maxima, sympy). [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11032015/4279).

Соответственно есть случаи, когда концентрированные усилия, используя очевидные подходы, результат не дают, тогда стоит  отвлечься на какое-то время, переключиться на другие задачи. Озарение может прийти в самый неожиданный момент (но это уже за рамками "навскидку").

---

Посмотрите какие алгоритмы используются в задачах, которые вам интересны. Новые алгоритмы с лучшей сложностью не каждый день появляются.

Начните с самого простого кода на вашем языке, framework и узнайте его сложность (к примеру, "удаление по индексу элемента из массива"). Зная сложность для элементарных конструкций, найдите сложность для блоков кода (составленных из этих конструкций), с которыми вы часто встречаетесь.

Можно в обратную сторону: начать с более высокоуровневого кода и постепенно спускаться ниже по уровням абстракции, пока до известных блоков не дойдёте (сложение фиксированных чисел, которые в машинном слове помещаются: O(1). Если произвольное число `n` взять, то O(log n) — пропорционально количеству бит в числе). См. [таблицу сложностей по времени](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0).

Практикуйтесь, пока большинство повседневного интересного вам кода не сможете навскидку оценить.

Comment: А где в документации пишут сложность операции в выбранном framework? Может, какие-то ключевые слова подскажете для поиска?

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов: я сомневаюсь, что в большинстве framework вы прямо в документации найдёте подробный анализ временной сложности (time complexity) используемых алгоритмов (если это популярный язык, то можно ожидать, что временные сложности разумные, хотя конечно баги бывают. К примеру, [`Array#reject!` в Ruby случайно имел квадратичную сложность](https://goo.gl/mvtDVq), его [документация](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) ничего о сложности не говорит. Вот [в ответе линейный алгоритм и объяснение почему линейность это желаемое свойство](https://goo.gl/JWFQxv)