# Как посчитать количество кубиков в квадратной лестнице, зная длину(формула)?

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Есть лестница, в которой на каждом следующем по высоте уровне на 1 ступеньку меньше, например, вот как выглядит лесенка длиной 4 с общим количеством ступенек 10:

**X

XX

XXX

XXXX**

И, что еще более интересно, *есть ли способ вывода формул*, если видна закономерность?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Типичная [арифметическая прогрессия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F). Класс 8, что ли...

```
1+2+3+...+n = n(n+1)/2
```

Если вы видите закономерность, то ее надо не выводить, а доказывать - методом [математической индукции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), например...

Comment: Еще не прошли. 9 класс. Спасибо.

Comment: Да нет проблем, значит, скоро :) Про Гаусса вам не рассказывали? как учитель задал посчитать сумму чисел от 1 до 100, на что малец заметил, что это - 50 пар: 1+100, 2+99, 3+98 и так далее, и все равны 101... :) Так и здесь...

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае: [`a(i+1) = a(i) + 1`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a(i%2B1)+%3D+a(i)+%2B+1,a(1)%3D1). Вы хотите найти сумму: [`sum(a(i), i=1..n)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(i,+i%3D1..n)). То есть зная рекуррентную формулу для последовательности, можно найти замкнутую формулу для суммы:

```py
  n                
 ___               
 ╲                 
  ╲        n⋅(n + 1)
  ╱   i  = ─────────
 ╱            2    
 ‾‾‾               
i = 1
```

Формулу может помочь найти [`sympy`](http://www.sympy.org/) (или другая система символьных вычислений):

```py
>>> from sympy import Function, Sum, rsolve
>>> from sympy.abc import i, n
>>> a = Function('a')
>>> rsolve(a(i+1)-a(i)-1, a(i), {a(1):1})
i
>>> Sum(i, (i, 1, n)).doit()
 2    
n    n
── + ─
2    2
```

Хотя в таких тривиальных случаях это может и перебор — это демонстрирует общую технику, которая может и в других случаях пригодиться. Ещё примеры:

- [Алгоритмы. Сколько раз вызывается print() в функции? Временная сложность циклов с половинным делением i /= 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/581596/23044)
- [Найти частичную сумму знакопеременного ряда с факториалом: sum (-1)^k (k + 1) / k!, k=0..n](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/728795/23044)